# If element is in a vector, all group takes some value in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset like **countries**

```
disjoint_set <- c("CUW", "ARM")

id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
period <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2)
iso <- c("CUW","USA","ARM","SPA","CUW","ARM","CHN","ARM","USA","CHN","ARM","GER")

countries <- data.frame(id, period, iso)
```

Grouping by **id,period** I want to assign 1 if some element of variable **iso** is in vector **disjoint_set**, 0 otherwise (I want 1's or 0's for all the elements of the group defined). The new dataset will look like **countries_not_appear**

```
disjoint = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0)
countries_not_appear <- data.frame(id, period, iso, disjoint)
```

I have tried the following. But it doesn't make the trick

```
countries_not_appear <- countries %>% group_by(id, period) %>% mutate(disjoint = ifelse(iso %in% disjoint_set, 1, 0))
```

Any clue?

Comment: `as.numeric(ave(countries$iso, paste(countries$id, countries$period), FUN = function(x) +(any(x %in% disjoint_set))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
countries %>%
  group_by(id, period) %>%
  mutate(disjoint = +any(iso %in% disjoint_set)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
      id period iso   disjoint
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <int>
 1     1      1 CUW          1
 2     1      1 USA          1
 3     1      2 ARM          1
 4     1      2 SPA          1
 5     2      1 CUW          1
 6     2      2 ARM          1
 7     2      3 CHN          0
 8     2      4 ARM          1
 9     3      1 USA          1
10     3      1 CHN          1
11     3      1 ARM          1
12     3      2 GER          0
```

Answer (score 3):

`ifelse` compares row wise. If you want to check per group use `any`:

```r
library(dplyr)

disjoint_set <- c("CUW", "ARM")

id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
period <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2)
iso <- c("CUW","USA","ARM","SPA","CUW","ARM","CHN","ARM","USA","CHN","ARM","GER")

countries <- data.frame(id, period, iso)

countries_not_appear <- data.frame(id, period, iso, disjoint)
#> Error in data.frame(id, period, iso, disjoint): object 'disjoint' not found

countries %>% 
  group_by(id, period) %>% 
  mutate(disjoint = as.numeric(any(iso %in% disjoint_set)))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   id, period [8]
#>       id period iso   disjoint
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     1      1 CUW          1
#>  2     1      1 USA          1
#>  3     1      2 ARM          1
#>  4     1      2 SPA          1
#>  5     2      1 CUW          1
#>  6     2      2 ARM          1
#>  7     2      3 CHN          0
#>  8     2      4 ARM          1
#>  9     3      1 USA          1
#> 10     3      1 CHN          1
#> 11     3      1 ARM          1
#> 12     3      2 GER          0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You may follow the following lines of code as per your query -->

```r
disjoint_set = c ("CUW", "ARM")

id = c (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)

period = c (1,1,2,2,1, 2, 3, 4, 1,1,1,2)

ISO = c ("CUW", "USA", "ARM", "SPA", "CUW", "ARM", "CHN", "ARM", "USA", "CHN",
         "ARM", "GER")

countries = data.frame (id, period, ISO)

countries

countries $Not.Appear = ifelse (test = countries $ISO == disjoint_set,
                                    yes = 1, no = 0)
```

[Output of the data frame, as required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMYaJ.png)